# Getting RDS Days Since Last Connection information using Boto3 Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-rds

We are trying to find and shutdown / delete all RDS which were not accessed or connected to from any applications since last 14+ days and are idle. We are using boto3 to get list of all RDS and other details but unable to find "Days Since Last Connection" as reported by Trusted Advisor.

Following is our python code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import boto3

try:

    # get all of the db instances
    rds = boto3.client('rds')
    instance = rds.describe_db_instances()

    for i in instance['DBInstances']:
        print(i['DBInstanceIdentifier'], i['DBInstanceClass'], i['Engine'], i['AllocatedStorage'], i['AvailabilityZone'], i['MultiAZ'], i['EngineVersion'], i['PubliclyAccessible'], i['StorageType'], i['DbInstancePort'], i['StorageEncrypted'], i['IAMDatabaseAuthenticationEnabled'], i['PerformanceInsightsEnabled'], i['DeletionProtection'], i['NetworkType'])

except Exception as error:
    print(error)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look into RDS Cloudwatch log for the connection count

> ConnectionAttempts
>
> - The number of attempts to connect to an instance, whether successful or not.
> - This metric is available only for RDS for MySQL.
>
> DatabaseConnections
>
> - The number of client network connections to the database instance.
> - The number of database sessions can be higher than the metric value because the metric value doesn't include the following:
> - Sessions that no longer have a network connection but which the database hasn't cleaned up
> - Sessions created by the database engine for its own purposes
> - Sessions created by the database engine's parallel execution capabilities
> - Sessions created by the database engine job scheduler
>
> Amazon RDS connections

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-metrics.html